# child objects drawing order

Tags: javascript, three.js

Got the following problem:

im trying to make rings around saturn, but it seems they are somehow rendered in wrong order:

[image]

The thing is how each planet is created. Each planet is a child of different root object (THREE.Object3d), which contains a bodyContainer (THREE.Object3d). BodyContainer contains the planet mesh. When I add the rings mesh to body or bodycontainer it is rendered as on the picture above.

For tests ive created a 'free' sphere and rings, which ive added. to the scene and everything works as supposed for objects added directly to the scene.

Even if I add rings as a child of the sphere which is added to the scene it works fine.

Here is the code I use to generate the planet body:

```
export default function generateBody(radius, basic, name) {


  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, 24, 24 );
  var material;
  if(basic) {
      material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFBE200});
  } else {
      material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        //depthWrite: false,
        //depthTest: true,
      });

        if(textures[name].hasOwnProperty('map')) material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(textures[name].map);
        if(textures[name].hasOwnProperty('bump')) material.bumpMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(textures[name].bump);
        if(textures[name].hasOwnProperty('specular')) material.specularMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(textures[name].specular);
        if(textures[name].hasOwnProperty('normal')) material.normalMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(textures[name].specular);
  }

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )
  mesh.scale.set( params.bodyScale, params.bodyScale, params.bodyScale );
  mesh.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
  mesh.renderOrder = 0;

  return mesh;
}
```

and how i add the rings:

```
  var circlemesh = new THREE.XRingGeometry(1.2 * (def && def.diameter || 139822000) * M_TO_AU / 2, 2 * (def && def.diameter || 139822000) * M_TO_AU / 2, 2 * 64, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  var circleMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('../img/planet-textures/saturn/saturnringcolor.jpg'),
    alphaMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('../img/planet-textures/saturn/saturnringpattern.gif'),
    //transparent: true,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    //depthWrite: false,
    //depthTest: true
  });
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(circlemesh, circleMaterial);
  mesh.renderOrder = 1;
  this.body.add(mesh);
```

furtheron:

```
this.bodyContainer.add(this.body)
this.root.add(this.bodyContainer)
scene.add(this.root)
```

For testing on a sphere added directly to the scene i use just a plain sphere geometry and the same mesh for rings used here.

```
        var circlemesh = new THREE.XRingGeometry(1.2 * 5, 2 * 5, 2 * 64, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      var circleMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('../img/planet-textures/saturn/saturnringcolor.jpg'),
        alphaMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('../img/planet-textures/saturn/saturnringpattern.gif'),
        transparent: true,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        //depthWrite: false,
        //depthTest: true
      });
      var ringmesh = new THREE.Mesh(circlemesh, circleMaterial);
      //ringmesh.renderOrder = 1;
      //scene.add(ringmesh);

var SPHEREgeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 32, 32 );
var SPHEREmaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( SPHEREgeometry, SPHEREmaterial );
//sphere.renderOrder = 0;
scene.add( sphere );
```

sphere.add( ringmesh );

[image]

Comment: What happens when you set depthTest: true, depthWrite: true for your materials and then you comment out the mesh.renderorder statements?

Comment: @pprchsvr nothing changes

Comment: Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pprchsvr/zw21yhdh/) to see if it will help.  depthTest and depthWrite default to true in any event.

Comment: @pprchsvr thanks, it works in the fiddle ok, but in the app not. I think it may be something connected with parents rotation and position setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed the problem was increasing the near of the camera.
No extra parameters in material weren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use Object3D in a parent child setup in THREE:

[Object3D Parent Child Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pprchsvr/zw21yhdh/)

```
var root = new THREE.Object3D();
var rootcontainer = new THREE.Object3D();
root.parent = rootcontainer;
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
root.add( mesh );
rootcontainer.add(root);
scene.add(rootcontainer);
```